# Android force close when button clicked

Tags: android, eclipse, button, forceclose

The application force close when i click button. My java, xml and manifest have no error. I don't understand why the application could be force closing when I click the button.
this is the java code.

```
package com.aza.geopi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button materi;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    materi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    materi.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view){
    if (view==materi) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MenuActivity.this, materi.class);
        startActivityForResult (intent, 0);
    }
}

}
```

this is the xml code

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainmenu"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MenuActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_x="80dp"
    android:layout_y="160dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_x="88dp"
    android:layout_y="256dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_x="80dp"
    android:layout_y="355dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="" />
```

the second class

```
package com.aza.geopi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class materi extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.materi);
    }
}
```

the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aza.geopi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.aza.geopi.MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="materi">
    </activity> 
</application>
```

logcat

> ```
> >  05-15 08:59:55.977: D/dalvikvm(272): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 745
> > objects / 54592 bytes in 76ms
> >     05-15 09:00:04.106: E/dalvikvm-heap(272): 18933750-byte external allocation too large for this process.
> >     05-15 09:00:04.106: E/GraphicsJNI(272): VM won't let us allocate 18933750 bytes
> >     05-15 09:00:04.126: D/AndroidRuntime(272): Shutting down VM
> >     05-15 09:00:04.126: W/dalvikvm(272): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> > ComponentInfo{com.aza.geopi/com.aza.geopi.materi}:
> > android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> > inflating class <unknown>
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> > inflating class <unknown>
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.aza.geopi.materi.onCreate(materi.java:11)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  ... 11 more
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:47)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  ... 21 more
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
> >     05-15 09:00:04.196: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  ... 25 more
> >     05-15 09:00:08.805: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 272 SIG: 9
> >     05-15 09:24:41.886: D/dalvikvm(301): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 767 objects / 55448 bytes in 77ms
> >     05-15 09:25:13.296: E/dalvikvm-heap(301): 18933750-byte external allocation too large for this process.
> >     05-15 09:25:13.296: E/GraphicsJNI(301): VM won't let us allocate 18933750 bytes
> >     05-15 09:25:13.296: D/AndroidRuntime(301): Shutting down VM
> >     05-15 09:25:13.305: W/dalvikvm(301): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> > ComponentInfo{com.aza.geopi/com.aza.geopi.materi}:
> > android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> > inflating class <unknown>
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> > inflating class <unknown>
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.aza.geopi.materi.onCreate(materi.java:11)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  ... 11 more
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:47)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  ... 21 more
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
> >     05-15 09:25:13.336: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  ... 25 more
> >     05-15 09:25:15.475: I/Process(301): Sending signal. PID: 301 SIG: 9
> >     05-15 09:41:23.535: D/dalvikvm(330): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 789 objects / 56304 bytes in 83ms
> >     05-15 09:41:30.596: E/dalvikvm-heap(330): 18933750-byte external allocation too large for this process.
> >     05-15 09:41:30.596: E/GraphicsJNI(330): VM won't let us allocate 18933750 bytes
> >     05-15 09:41:30.606: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
> >     05-15 09:41:30.606: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> > ComponentInfo{com.aza.geopi/com.aza.geopi.materi}:
> > android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> > inflating class <unknown>
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> > inflating class <unknown>
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.aza.geopi.materi.onCreate(materi.java:11)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 11 more
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:47)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 21 more
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:285)
> >     05-15 09:41:30.646: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 25 more
> ```

thanks before

Answer (score 2):

The error is "out of memory". It looks like you are using a very large bitmap which is using all the memory your app can access on the device or emulator you are using.